# User not authenticated after calling req.logIn

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

```
req.logIn(user, function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.end("Success!"); // this is returned to my client
});
```

I am calling this, and on the client side, user is still not authenticated:

```
window.user
```

This is empty, but should be set.

I was following mean.IO. Ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.login` works on the server side, the `window` object is on the client.  There is no link between them.  You could do `res.cookie('mycookie', myvalue)` on the server-side and then parse the cookie on the client side, but that linking is up to you to create.

Comment: How it works on mean.io? Something generates the link there automagically.